# Regex find string between first string and the first instance of another string using Notepad++

Tags: regex, string, search, notepad++

Sorry - I've edited this for clarity (and I've tried to remove the bold later in the post, but it's not going away...the asterisks in the source file are throwing it off):

I'm parsing medical claim files and need to find any instances of a match between one string and another but only if the match appears before another string is satisfied.

The specific strings between which I want to search are DTP*431 and REF*6R (I'm including the DTP*431 as part of it, since it will be eliminated under certain circumstances).

I need the regex to return a match if the 8 digits immediately following DTP*431*D8* exactly match the 8 digits immediately following the next instance of DTP*472*RD8* in the file, and to not continue the search after the 8 digits immediately following the next instance of DTP*472*RD8*

This example should not return a match, because the 8 digits immediately after DTP*431*D8* (20150101) do not match the 8 digits immediately following the next instance of DTP*472*RD8* (20150102):

DTP*431*D8*20150101~
[variable text in between]
LX*1~
DTP*472*RD8*20150102-20150102~
REF*6R*[more information]~
[variable text in between]
DTP*431*D8*20141231~
[variable text in between]
LX*1~
DTP*472*RD8*20150103-20150103~
REF*6R*[more information]~

This example should return a match, but should only reflect a match, because the 8 digits immediately following DTP*431*D8* (20150101) exactly match the 8 digits immediately following the first instance of DTP*472*RD8* appearing in the file (20150101):

DTP*431*D8*20150101~
[variable text in between]
LX*1~
DTP*472*RD8*20150101-20150101~
REF*6R*[more information]~
[variable text in between]
DTP*431*D8*20141231~
[variable text in between]
LX*1~
DTP*472*RD8*20150102-20150102~
REF*6R*[more information]~

This example should not return a match, because even though there is a match between the first 8 digits after an instance of DTP*431*D8* and an instance of DTP*472*RD8* (20150101), it is not the next instance of DTP*472*RD8* that provides that match:

DTP*431*D8*20150101~
[variable text in between]
LX*1~
DTP*472*RD8*20150103-20150103~
REF*6R*[more information]~
[variable text in between]
DTP*431*D8*20141231~
[variable text in between]
LX*1~
DTP*472*RD8*20150101-20150101~
REF*6R*[more information]~

Here's what I have so far:

(DTP*431*D8*)(?<=\DTP*431*D8*)([0-9]{8})(.*?)(?=\DTP*472)(DTP*472*RD8*)(\2)

...but if the date in the first instance of DTP*472 doesn't match, it is continuing past the first DTP*472 and looking until it finds any DTP*472 with a date that matches the \1 element.

So if I searched the following text, it would (undesirably) match the bolded portion:

**DTP*431*D8*20150101~**
**[variable text in between]**
**LX*1~**
**DTP*472*RD8*20150102-20150102~**
**REF*6R*[more information]~**
**[variable text in between]**
**DTP*431*D8*20141231~**
**[variable text in between]**
**LX*1~**
**DTP*472*RD8*20150101**-20150101~
REF*6R*[more information]~


What I'm trying to do is this delete the entire line of DTP*431*D8* if the 8 digits immediately following DTP*431*D8* exactly match the 8 digits immediately following the very next instance of DTP*472*RD8*

Here is a sample I got off the net and modified (I can't use actual data).  This item should produce a match:

ISA*00*          *01*SECRET    *ZZ*SUBMITTERS.ID  *ZZ*RECEIVERS.ID   *150101*0001*^*00501*00000001*1*T*:~
GS*HC*SENDER CODE*RECEIVER CODE*0*0001*1*X*005010X222~
ST*837*0021*005010X222~
BHT*0019*00*244579*20150101*1023*CH~
NM1*41*2*BILLING SERVICE*****46*9999999~
PER*IC*DOE*JOHN*3055552222*EX*111~
NM1*40*2*ABC INSURANCE COMPANY*****46*1111111~
HL*1* * 20*1~
PRV*BI*PXC*1234597890~
NM1*85*2*DOCTOR OFFICE*****XX*9876543210~
N3*1234 MAIN ST~
N4*LOS ANGELES*CA*11111~
REF*EI*222222222~
NM1*87*2~
N3*2345 MAIN ST~
N4*LOS ANGELES*CA*11111~
HL*2*1*22*1~
SBR*P********CI~
NM1*IL*1*DOE*JANE****MI*11332255~
DMG*D8*10000101*O~
NM1*PR*2*DEF INSURANCE COMPANY*****PI*999996666~
HL*3*2*23*0~
PAT*19~
NM1*QC*1*JONES*JOHN~
N3*111 N MAIN ST~
N4*LOS ANGELES*CA*22222~
DMG*D8*10000202*O~
CLM*888888*1***11:B:1*Y*A*Y*I~
DTP*431*D8*20150201~
REF*D9*1~
HI*BK:9999*BF:V999~
LX*1~
SV1*HC:99999*1*UN*1***1~
DTP*472*RD8*20150101-20150201~
REF*6R*000001~
SE*33*0021~
GE*1*1~
IEA*1*000000001~

Using this, if my match is found, I'd delete the DTP*431*D8 line entirely and the file would then appear as below:

ISA*00*          *01*SECRET    *ZZ*SUBMITTERS.ID  *ZZ*RECEIVERS.ID   *150101*0001*^*00501*00000001*1*T*:~
GS*HC*SENDER CODE*RECEIVER CODE*0*0001*1*X*005010X222~
ST*837*0021*005010X222~
BHT*0019*00*244579*20150101*1023*CH~
NM1*41*2*BILLING SERVICE*****46*9999999~
PER*IC*DOE*JOHN*3055552222*EX*111~
NM1*40*2*ABC INSURANCE COMPANY*****46*1111111~
HL*1**20*1~

PRV*BI*PXC*1234597890~

NM1*85*2*DOCTOR OFFICE*****XX*9876543210~

N3*1234 MAIN ST~

N4*LOS ANGELES*CA*11111~

REF*EI*222222222~

NM1*87*2~

N3*2345 MAIN ST~

N4*LOS ANGELES*CA*11111~

HL*2*1*22*1~

SBR*P********CI~

NM1*IL*1*DOE*JANE****MI*11332255~

DMG*D8*10000101*O~

NM1*PR*2*DEF INSURANCE COMPANY*****PI*999996666~

HL*3*2*23*0~

PAT*19~

NM1*QC*1*JONES*JOHN~

N3*111 N MAIN ST~

N4*LOS ANGELES*CA*22222~

DMG*D8*10000202*O~

CLM*888888*1***11:B:1*Y*A*Y*I~

REF*D9*1~

HI*BK:9999*BF:V999~

LX*1~

SV1*HC:99999*1*UN*1***1~

DTP*472*RD8*20150101-20150201~

REF*6R*000001~

SE*33*0021~

GE*1*1~

IEA*1*000000001~




Conversely, this item would not get a match and the file would be left as is:



ISA*00*          *01*SECRET    *ZZ*SUBMITTERS.ID  *ZZ*RECEIVERS.ID   *150101*0001*^*00501*00000001*1*T*:~

GS*HC*SENDER CODE*RECEIVER CODE*0*0001*1*X*005010X222~

ST*837*0021*005010X222~

BHT*0019*00*244579*20150101*1023*CH~

NM1*41*2*BILLING SERVICE*****46*9999999~

PER*IC*DOE*JOHN*3055552222*EX*111~

NM1*40*2*ABC INSURANCE COMPANY*****46*1111111~

HL*1**20*1~
PRV*BI*PXC*1234597890~
NM1*85*2*DOCTOR OFFICE*****XX*9876543210~
N3*1234 MAIN ST~
N4*LOS ANGELES*CA*11111~
REF*EI*222222222~
NM1*87*2~
N3*2345 MAIN ST~
N4*LOS ANGELES*CA*11111~
HL*2*1*22*1~
SBR*P********CI~
NM1*IL*1*DOE*JANE****MI*11332255~
DMG*D8*10000101*O~
NM1*PR*2*DEF INSURANCE COMPANY*****PI*999996666~
HL*3*2*23*0~
PAT*19~
NM1*QC*1*JONES*JOHN~
N3*111 N MAIN ST~
N4*LOS ANGELES*CA*22222~
DMG*D8*10000202*O~
CLM*888888*1***11:B:1*Y*A*Y*I~
DTP*431*D8*20150201~
REF*D9*1~
HI*BK:9999*BF:V999~
LX*1~
SV1*HC:99999*1*UN*1***1~
DTP*472*RD8*20150102-20150202~
REF*6R*000001~
SE*33*0021~
GE*1*1~
IEA*1*000000001~

Comment: Problem is not the start but the _end_. In your first example what makes it move past the `REF*6R*[` ? Are you looking for balanced start/end ?

Comment: I'm not sure what a balanced start/end is.  I wish I was better at this but most of what I've learned comes from having perused websites with no formal instruction.  I'm reading up on balanced starts and endings now and might have an answer to that shortly.  :)

Comment: Completely unclear. Please EDIT your question adding 1) The exact rules you want to reproduce, 2) A couple of examples with a clear explanation of why they should fail or success

Comment: I think you pointed me in the right direction.  The problem is I don't know what I don't know.

So would I do this?

(?'open'(DTP\*431\*D8\*)([0-9]{8}))+(?'-open'DTP\*472\*\2)+

Comment: @BartlebytheScrivener you question is not clear enough, can you post sample data and expected output?

Comment: Sorry folks, I've edited the heck out of this and hope it's a bit clearer.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, redone. Looking at your samples now.
It gets very complicated. There are many things going on.

To try to explain it would be tedious. So, I've put all the explanation in the
regex comments.

Just replace the match with "" and you should be good to go.

Formatting, debug, testing and analysis by [RegexFormat 5](http://www.regexformat.com).

```
 # (?sm)(?:^[ \t]*DTP\*\d{3}\*R?D\d\*(\d{8})[^\r\n]*\r?\n(?=(?:(?!^[ \t]*DTP\*\d{3}\*R?D\d\*).)*^[ \t]*DTP\*\d{3}\*R?D\d\*(?:\1|\d{8}-\1).*?^[ \t]*REF\*6R)|^[ \t]*DTP\*\d{3}\*R?D\d\*\d{8}-(\d{8})[^\r\n]*\r?\n(?=(?:(?!^[ \t]*DTP\*\d{3}\*R?D\d\*).)*^[ \t]*DTP\*\d{3}\*R?D\d\*(?:\2|\d{8}-\2).*?^[ \t]*REF\*6R))

 (?sm)
 (?:
      ^ [ \t]* DTP\* \d{3} \*R?D \d \*
      ( \d{8} )                           # (1), Checking "first" NUMBER spot
      [^\r\n]* \r? \n                     # Grab the rest of this line

      (?=                                 # Lookahead 
           (?:                                 # Not a DTP line
                (?! ^ [ \t]* DTP\* \d{3} \*R?D \d \* )
                . 
           )*
           ^ [ \t]* DTP\* \d{3} \*R?D \d \*    # The very next 'DTP' line
           (?: \1 | \d{8} - \1 )               # Number must be in one of these spots
           .*? ^ [ \t]* REF\*6R                # The ending
      )

   |                                    ## Or, 

      ^ [ \t]* DTP\* \d{3} \*R?D \d \*
      \d{8} - 
      ( \d{8} )                           # (2), Checking "second" NUMBER spot
      [^\r\n]* \r? \n                     # Grab the rest of this line

      (?=                                 # Lookahead
           (?:                                 # Not a DTP line
                (?! ^ [ \t]* DTP\* \d{3} \*R?D \d \* )
                . 
           )*
           ^ [ \t]* DTP\* \d{3} \*R?D \d \*    # The very next 'DTP' line
           (?: \2 | \d{8} - \2 )               # Number must be in one of these spots
           .*? ^ [ \t]* REF\*6R                # The ending
      )
 )
```

You might want to turn the *Lookaheads* into a capture group ( `(?=..)` to `(..)` then adjust the backrefs to point to `\1` and `\3`.
At this point the replacement is just `\2\4` or `$2$4`.
What this does is move the search position past the ending, avoiding possible overlap.

```
 # (?sm)(?:^[ \t]*DTP\*\d{3}\*R?D\d\*(\d{8})[^\r\n]*\r?\n((?:(?!^[ \t]*DTP\*\d{3}\*R?D\d\*).)*^[ \t]*DTP\*\d{3}\*R?D\d\*(?:\1|\d{8}-\1).*?^[ \t]*REF\*6R)|^[ \t]*DTP\*\d{3}\*R?D\d\*\d{8}-(\d{8})[^\r\n]*\r?\n((?:(?!^[ \t]*DTP\*\d{3}\*R?D\d\*).)*^[ \t]*DTP\*\d{3}\*R?D\d\*(?:\3|\d{8}-\3).*?^[ \t]*REF\*6R))

 (?sm)
 (?:
      ^ [ \t]* DTP\* \d{3} \*R?D \d \*
      ( \d{8} )                           # (1), Checking "first" NUMBER spot
      [^\r\n]* \r? \n                     # Grab the rest of this line

      (                                   # (2 start), Part to be written back 
           (?:                                 # Not a DTP line
                (?! ^ [ \t]* DTP\* \d{3} \*R?D \d \* )
                . 
           )*
           ^ [ \t]* DTP\* \d{3} \*R?D \d \*    # The very next 'DTP' line
           (?: \1 | \d{8} - \1 )               # Number must be in one of these spots
           .*? ^ [ \t]* REF\*6R                # The ending
      )                                   # (2 end)

   |                                    ## Or, 

      ^ [ \t]* DTP\* \d{3} \*R?D \d \*
      \d{8} - 
      ( \d{8} )                           # (3), Checking "second" NUMBER spot
      [^\r\n]* \r? \n                     # Grab the rest of this line

      (                                   # (4 start), Part to be written back
           (?:                                 # Not a DTP line
                (?! ^ [ \t]* DTP\* \d{3} \*R?D \d \* )
                . 
           )*
           ^ [ \t]* DTP\* \d{3} \*R?D \d \*    # The very next 'DTP' line
           (?: \3 | \d{8} - \3 )               # Number must be in one of these spots
           .*? ^ [ \t]* REF\*6R                # The ending
      )                                   # (4 end)
 )
```

Comment: I'm hoping my edited entry gives clarity, but this has the same issue my first example has.  If the first instance of DTP*472*RD8*<date> doesn't match, it continues the search until it finds one that does.

Comment: @BartlebytheScrivener - Fortunately, that's exactly what this regex does. Did you examin the _Output_ ?

Comment: Edit: I think I missed something.  It's actually starting with a different DTP segment in my production file and that threw me off.  I'm re-testing now.

Comment: I've tried editing it to only use the 431 to start and the 472 to end and it's going past the first 472 to find the next instance of a 472 that has a date matching that of the first.  I've also tried leaving the 472 as just being \d{3} to no avail.

Comment: @BartlebytheScrivener - Have a look at the modified one.

Comment: I had to modify it a bit, because it was capturing other types of DTP segments, but I got it working (all credit goes to you - I was doing hit or miss monkey work to get it work ignore the others, you put in the thinking and work - I appreciate it a LOT!).

Comment: Sorry - here's what I ended up using:

(?sm)(?:^[ \t]*DTP\*431\*R?D\d\*(\d{8})[^\r\n]*\r?\n(?=(?:(?!^[ \t]*DTP\*\d{3}\*R?D\d\*).)*^[ \t]*DTP\*\d{3}\*R?D\d\*(?:\1|\d{8}-\1).*?^[ \t]*REF\*6R)|^[ \t]*DTP\*431\*R?D\d\*\d{8}-(\d{8})[^\r\n]*\r?\n(?=(?:(?!^[ \t]*DTP\*431\*R?D\d\*).)*^[ \t]*DTP\*472\*R?D\d\*(?:\2|\d{8}-\2).*?^[ \t]*REF\*6R))

Comment: @BartlebytheScrivener - Great! I highly recommend getting [RegexFormat 5](http://www.regexformat.com) app to do this stuff. Turns days of frustration into 20 minutes of bliss.

Comment: *cry*  That would have saved me about 60 hours of work!  I'll be getting it next week!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I understood your question, but assuming you want to capture the content between `DTP*431` and `REF*6R` incluiding `DTP*431`, then you can use this regex:

```
(DTP\*431.*?)REF\*6R
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oP9xN4/1)**

You save the content into a capturing group discarding REF*6R. You can see in blue the matches and in green the capturing group content.

[image]